# How to verify the value of the data-qtip of button?

Tags: extjs, selenium-ide, selenium-iedriver

I'm making an automated test on IE8, and i need to verify the hint of a button, the site I'm automating uses extjs, and for some reason, IE8 and Selenium IDE with the IEDriver don't work very well when it comes to the command "mouseOver". I did the following on Selenium IDE in Firefox and it worked:

```
<tr>
    <td>mouseOver</td>
    <td>//span[text()='Relatórios de Retorno']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForVisible</td>
    <td>id=ext-quicktips-tip-innerCt</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>id=ext-quicktips-tip-innerCt</td>
    <td>Gera relatórios de retorno</td>
</tr>
```

But it doesn't work on IE for some reason, even if i stop the Selenium IDE and the driver, and go "manually" with the mouse over the button, the hint don't popup, so i was thinking in try to verify it directly by the data-qtip, but i don't know how.Here's the button code i took with the F12 on IE8, i want to verify the value of the data-tip:

```
<A aria-disabled=false aria-hidden=false hideFocus style="MARGIN: 0px; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 495px" id=aejs-button-1104 class="x-btn x-unselectable x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-medium" role=button tabIndex=-1 unselectable="on" data-componentid="aejs-button-1104" data-qtip="Gera relatórios de retorno">
```

Comment: How are the 2 `HTML`s `<tr>...<tr>` and `<a>` related to each other?

Comment: The first code, is the code i did on the Selenium IDE to put the mouse over the button and check the hint.

The second piece of code is just the HTML part of the button i took with the F12 on IE8(F12, select the button on the page, and it shows where the button is on the code).

Comment: Your code trials please.

Comment: You mean the IDE log when i run the code or the entire code? Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the command "verifyAttribute", here's how i did it:

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyAttribute</td>
    <td>id=aejs-button-1104@data-qtip</td>
    <td>Gera relatórios de retorno</td>
</tr>
```